# Make a menu visible for a single category and it's content

Tags: categories

I'm working on a site with 3 major sections. Therefore I want to create archives for each section and those archives should be visible only in the category page and it's posts.
At this point, I made the menu visible only for the category page, but when I open a post, the widget is not displayed.

How do I create archives for specific categories, and how do I display them in a specific category and its posts?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display any specific conditional content on a single post based on it's category, you have to edit the template called `single.php`.
e.g. put something like this in single.php

```
if ( in_category( 'category1' )) {
    //code for category1
} elseif ( in_category( array( 'category2', 'category3' ) )) {
    // code for when t
} else {
    // code for others
}
```